# Requirement for Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have stored user data (including the FirebaseInstanceId token) on my server. And now I want to use Firebase Cloud Messaging. How can I do it without using Firebase Auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FCM and Firebase Auth are services that can work on their own without the other.

Requirements wise, in order for you to send the messages, you just need the correct *registration token* (FirebaseInstanceId token). You can either use the Firebase Console to send a message or your own app server using the REST API.

You could also make use of [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) since you are also using the Firebase Database.